# Trailing Slash .NET MVC with URL Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7

If I add the rule to enforce a trailing slash to the urls in my application, it breaks when I redirect to a parameterized URL, such as www.mysite.com/state/city?lat=x&lng=y

Does anyone know how to handle trailing slashes when such parameters exist?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at RouteConfig.cs and routes.AppendTrailingSlash see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet bu I have a feeling this is correct because of other changes to routing.